# Python pexpect timeout when entering password on scp command

Tags: python, ssh, timeout, scp, pexpect

I dont know how to describe it, just nothing happens in a while and then suddenly I get this. Im new with this module and I really dont know why I get this error: `pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking()`. 
My code:

```
import pexpect 
child = pexpect.spawn('scp abc user@ip:')
child.expect('Password .*:')
child.sendline('pwd')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you try:

```
child.expect('Password .*:', timeout=None)
```